# Find order of jobs from schedule table?

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

I'm attempting to write out a batch job schedule based on a table stored in an Oracle database.

I really have no idea where to start.

The table only has two relevant columns:

```
JOBSTREAM     |   FOLLOW_JOBSTREAM
```

JOBSTREAM is the name of the job stream that is going to run.  FOLLOW_JOBSTREAM is the name of the job stream that **must be completed** before the jobstream runs.  In some instances, one JOBSTREAM entry has several FOLLOW_JOBSTREAM entries.

For example:

```
JS001      JS028
JS001A     JS039
JS001B     JS001A
JS002      JS001A
JS002      JS001B
```

Is there a way to sort these using PL/SQL?

Thank you!

Comment: in your example what jobstream would run first?

Comment: @Goat_CO Thanks for the tip! Any good resources for Oracle CTE?

Comment: @ChrisCamp - Good question.  There is another table that contains jobs that are started at a specific time.  Upon completion, those jobs kick off jobs based off of the FOLLOW_JOBSTREAM entries in this example table.  So, essentially, I know which jobs start the process, but I'm not sure how they follow.

Comment: I can't paste my answer for some reason.

Comment: Keep getting an error message when posting. Search for 'oracle employee/manager cte

Comment: Why do you want to write a stored procedure? (PL/SQL is **only** for stored procedures, everything else is just SQL)

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name Essentially, I am going to include this stored procedure at the beginning of the batch job process, so that it will populate an HTML representation of the job schedule prior to the batch run.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At first, we need full job list from both columns with hierarchy links:

```
  select  
    all_jobs.job_id              as jobstream,
    job_depends.follow_jobstream as parent_jobstream
  from
    (
      select jobstream job_id from job_list
      union
      select follow_jobstream job_id from job_list
    ) all_jobs,
    job_list job_depends
  where
    job_depends.jobstream (+) = all_jobs.job_id
```

Then determine the depth of each job.

```
with full_job_list as (
  select  
    all_jobs.job_id              as jobstream,
    job_depends.follow_jobstream as parent_jobstream
  from
    (
      select jobstream job_id from job_list
      union
      select follow_jobstream job_id from job_list
    ) all_jobs,
    job_list job_depends
  where
    job_depends.jobstream (+) = all_jobs.job_id
)
select 
  CONNECT_BY_ROOT jobstream            as jobstream, 
  level                                as lvl,
  CONNECT_BY_ROOT parent_jobstream     as preceding_jobstream,
  sys_connect_by_path(jobstream, '<-') as path_illustration
from
  full_job_list
connect by 
  prior parent_jobstream = jobstream
```

And finally arrange jobs according to depth. Jobs at same depth can work at any sequence.

```
with full_job_list as (
  select  
    all_jobs.job_id              as jobstream,
    job_depends.follow_jobstream as parent_jobstream
  from
    (
      select jobstream job_id from job_list
      union
      select follow_jobstream job_id from job_list
    ) all_jobs,
    job_list job_depends
  where
    job_depends.jobstream (+) = all_jobs.job_id
)
select 
  jobstream, 
  depth,
  preceding_jobstream
from (
  select distinct
    jobstream,
    ( 
      last_value(lvl ignore nulls) 
      over ( partition by jobstream 
             order by lvl 
             rows between unbounded preceding and unbounded following
           ) 
    ) as depth,
    (
      last_value(preceding_jobstream ignore nulls) 
      over ( partition by jobstream 
             order by lvl 
             rows between unbounded preceding and unbounded following
           ) 
    ) as preceding_jobstream
  from (
    select 
      CONNECT_BY_ROOT jobstream        as jobstream, 
      level                            as lvl,
      CONNECT_BY_ROOT parent_jobstream as preceding_jobstream
    from
      full_job_list
    connect by 
      prior parent_jobstream = jobstream
  )
)
order by depth, jobstream
```

[SQL Fiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!4/100c0/4)

**Update** Corrected to get full job list and added preceding jobs.

**Update2** Corrected error with path direction.

Comment: If "FOLLOW_JOBSTREAM is the name of the job stream that must be completed **before** the jobstream runs" then f.ex. `JS001` have to run **after** `JS028` and in your solution it seems to be exactly opposite (according to Fiddle you provided).

Comment: @Chorel Thank you, error corrected. Now tree built in right direction.

Comment: Wow!  This is incredible. This fetches the jobstreams in the correct order.  All I had to do was change each job_list reference to the actual table name.  Thank you so much!

Answer (score 1):

[Hierarchical queries](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/queries003.htm) can help you in such cases:

```
SELECT JOBSTREAM, FOLLOW_JOBSTREAM
FROM <jobstreams>
START WITH FOLLOW_JOBSTREAM NOT IN (SELECT JOBSTREAM 
                                    FROM jobstreams
                                   )
CONNECT BY PRIOR JOBSTREAM = FOLLOW_JOBSTREAM
```

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/f8cd2/22/0)

Comment: Don't work because one job can have 2 parents, e.g. JS001A in question.

Comment: It works - `JS001A` have only one parent (`JS039`). The one having two in this example is `JS002` and it is displayed properly after them. Notice that job in first column have to run after job in second column.

Comment: And what is the exact sequence of job in your answer and how this sequence can be determined by formal rules from resultset?

Comment: Question was about "sorting rules using PL/SQL", and so is the answer.

Answer (score 1):

There's an official Oracle method for linking multiple jobs together in a schedule.

DBMS_Scheduler allows you to define chains of jobs with dependencies based on the exit condition of previous steps in the chain. It is probably much more flexible and sophisticated than the home-grown method, so I would look at migrating to it in the future.

Comment: Thank you for your input.  The actual jobstream/job process is defined/run by a program called Tivoli Maestro Scheduler.  I just want to capture the schedule using this method.